# Give parameters to a function in Bash to a wp-cli program

Tags: wordpress, bash, function, alias

I saw a lot of bash alias problems when you want to give parameters to an alias, but i think that my is quite different.

This is the code that I want to do:

```
  wp post create --path="/var/www/html/web-page/" --post_status="publish" --post_category="$1" --post_title="$2" --edit
```

I can't do an alias, I need a function, so this is what I did:

```
post() {
    wp post create --path=/var/www/html/web-page/ --post_status=publish --post_category=$1 --post_title=$2 --edit;
            }
```

then i have this:

```
$post 4 test
$Error: Too many positional arguments: --post_title=
```

and if I do with simple quotes:

```
post() {
        wp post create --path='/var/www/html/web-page/' --post_status='publish' --post_category='$1' --post_title='$2' --edit;
                }
```

It doesn't take the parameters, it use the $1 and $2 as text.

But there is something wrong and I can't see it.

I think that is something with the syntaxis

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: You don't need and shouldn't use the `alias` command. Beyond that, perhaps you could be clearer on how your proposed solution fails to meet your expectations. (Probably you need to quote the parameter expansions.)

Comment: What is the error message reported? Do you try to define an alias by calling itself (`alias post="post"`)?

Comment: guys thanks it was a problem with the quotes, sometimes i don't get it how it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, it works!

I use the alias and it work with:

simple quotes and the variable without quotes:

```
  post() {
    wp post create --path='/var/www/html/web-page/' --post_status='publish' --post_category=$1 --post_title=$2 --edit'';
            }
alias post="post"
```

and it work also with doble quotes:

```
post() {
wp post create --path="/var/www/html/web-page/" --post_status="publish" --post_category="$1" --post_title="$2" --edit"";
        }
alias post="post"
```

and it also work with doble quotes and without the ; at the end

```
post() {
    wp post create --path="/var/www/html/web-page/" --post_status="publish" --post_category="$1" --post_title="$2" --edit""
            }
alias post="post"
```

and it also work with simple quotes and without the ; at the end

```
post() {
wp post create --path='/var/www/html/edgardo/' --post_status='publish' --post_category=$1 --post_title=$2 --edit''
        }
alias post="post"
```

It work with the alias and without the alias, i wrote down that just to show you, maybe it will help someone.

And when I want to give a post_title I can do it with '' and "" and it works but if the post_title doesn't have spaces it work without the quotes too.

Thanks a lot for your time, and sorry Im still learning...